# configuration-encrypter.bat in Java

Tags: java, java-8

As per the oracle documentation 
https://docs.oracle.com/html/E26106_01/Content/Security/Encrypt_User_Creds.htm

it says encrypt the password using the batch

```
"These properties are subsequently decrypted by the application at runtime."
```

does the JDK does the decryption during runtime???..please correct me if im wrong....

Actually im trying to encrypt the DB password which is in property file...

Comment: the link says "configuration-encrypter.bat " encrypts the password...correct me if im wrong... and cant i use this for my java application??..if not how to encrypt and decrypt the Db password which is stored in property file??/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securing a password in a properties file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306673/securing-a-password-in-a-properties-file)

Comment: Java does not do what you are after, you either have to to this on your own or enhance Javas functionality with a library.

Comment: @Marged. Before mentioning a **possible** duplicate, you may want to read that duplicate first.

Comment: @HeyStackexchange I did and think this provides a solution. What makes you think it does not ?