# Encrypt / Decrypt in Mule community edition

Tags: encryption, mule

How can we encrypt/ decrypt properties in mule community edition. As per my understanding Mule credential vault /security-property-placeholder are supported by enterprise edition. How can I achieve the same in Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually handle the encryption and decryption using custom java implementation. There is a thread in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306673/securing-a-password-in-a-properties-file) on how to implement the same using java.